# How can I tell Apache to serve these files for a Django app?

Tags: django, apache, static-files

I have this configuration in at the end of my httpd.conf:

```
<Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE myapp.settings
    PythonOption django.root /
    PythonDebug On
    PythonPath "['/my/path] + sys.path"

</Location>
```

This allows my application to startup, but the static files are not being served. I was thinking of adding something like this:

```
<Location "/site_media">
    # what to add here?
</Location>
```

And tell Apache to serve files from `/site_media/...` from `/my/path/myapp/media`. However, I cannot find a way to make the connection between /site_media and the actual path to my media directory. Could you guide me?

EDIT: I added this to httpd.conf:

```
Alias /site_media /my/path/myapp/media

<Directory /my/path/myapp/media>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location "/site_media">
</Location>
```

But, Apache still gives me 404 errors. I also tried to add a `SetHandler None` inside the `/site_media/` location element, but I still receive the same 404 error codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias), but read the full section.

Comment: I updated the question, but I still cannot access the static files. Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that because `Location` has `/`, that is where Apache thinks the static files will be served from. If I delete the `Location "/"` then I get my static files, but I don't have the app. Is there a way to allow both to exist, as they are?

Comment: I figured it out, I accidentally placed the `Location "/site_media"` above the `Location "/"` :). After I've put it below, it works! Thanks!